# modeling an "apply" object a to object b to create object c relationship

Tags: database-design, uml

I'm trying to come up with a data model/class diagram and I'm having trouble correctly representing this type of relationship in any meaningful way. Essentially it is as follows:

**Actor Z "applies" object A to object B, the output of which is object C.** A and B are both complex objects that are associated with a number of other objects. I guess in many ways it's similar to a "templating" situation where one uses a template to transform one object into a another? How would you model this in UML or something similar? (obviously this can be shown in sequence diagrams or workflow but I'm not really doing that - this is more a data/information model)

Comment: Where does the output come from ? Object B or Actor Z ? Anyway, interactions should be modeled with a sequence diagram. I don't see why you want to do it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing the Use Case Diagram, Class Diagram and may be Interaction Diagram.

The moment you say "Actor", I just see Use Case Diagram at a high level. Example: A Person (Actor) Drives a Car. But I am not sure your Object is a low level or something like the "Car"

However, you can also represent "Actor Z", "Class A", "Class B" and "Class C" as static Class diagram showing the relationships between them. My assumption is "Object A is instance of Class A" ... and so on. OR dynamic object interaction diagram as "Object A Object and Object C"

I believe you have all the flexibility ..